# View Column Types Not Supported - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, view

**UPDATE: This is now a ticket with System.Data.Sqlite.org. [Link](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=46166bd492)**

I have a view like similar to this in my SQLite database

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT fc.FilterCommandId, fc.ProcedureId, 1 AS IsDynamic, 
               substr(fc.DataType, 1, 20) || fc.Sequence AS Filter, fc.ObjectName 
        FROM ((FilterCommands fc INNER JOIN DynamicFilterCommands dfc 
             ON fc.FilterCommandId = dfc.FilterCommandId) 
        INNER JOIN DynamicFilterCommandFields dfcf 
             ON dfc.DynamicFilterCommandId = dfcf.DynamicFilterCommandId) 
        INNER JOIN ProcedureFilterKeys pfk ON fc.ProcedureId = pfk.ProcedureId 
        GROUP BY fc.FilterCommandId, fc.ProcedureId, 1, 
                 substr(fc.datatype, 1, 20) || fc.Sequence, fc.ObjectName
        ORDER BY fc.SortOrder
   ) AS sq 
   UNION 
   SELECT fc.FilterCommandId, fc.ProcedureId, 0, substr(fc.datatype, 1, 20) || fc.Sequence, 
          NULL
   FROM FilterCommands fc INNER JOIN StaticFilterCommands sfc 
        ON fc.FilterCommandId = sfc.FilterCommandId
)
```

The problem I am having is mapping all the columns in EF. I am getting Error Code 6005 (*The data type '' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version*) for several of the columns. It appears to affect literal values provided in the view (`1 AS IsDynamic`, for instance), and values taken directly from tables (`fc.ObjectName`, although this is provided the value of `NULL` for the second part of the `UNION` query)

This results in the columns not being mapped to the view. I want this view to be read only, so I am not worried about updating. But I would like the columns to be available for the application.

Has anyone experienced this issue, or have ideas on fixing?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. In my case, I observed that columns taken directly from tables are imported OK. It's only columns that are SQLITE expressions(that includes literal values exposed with the 'AS' keyword) that have the problem. Also, this happens even if you try to force the datatype of your expression using the CAST(... AS <datatype>) function in SQLITE. Anyone found the reason/solution for this?

Comment: Same problem here, i've read that sqlite uses dynamic typing and entity framework doesn't like that. But i didn't found any workaround regarding this issue.